# HTML p tag takes the height of its parent, not its content

Tags: html, css, paragraph

guys!

I'm using the tinyscrollbar plugin (jQuery), and I have to scroll paragraphs in a div with it. The problem is that the div (parent of the paragraphs) is 296px high and every paragraph takes 296px for its height and in the div I can view only one paragraph. I think, that it has to be done with css hack or something, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you set the height of your container at the moment?

Comment: the parent div? It's percentage (50% of window's height) with css

Comment: What is the window's height set to?

Answer (score 2):

The paragraphs have a height set to "inherit"

[**Here's an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/svQrt/)

Comment: ok, then how to DEinherit it? on your example there's nothing on the first paragraph

Comment: I set the height to 'auto' and everything looks perfect, except that it cuts a little bit of the content. I mean that the scroll is in the end, but the text is not. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you upload your code to jsFiddle.net for us to look at?

Comment: If you have a fixed number of paragraphs that you're displaying and a fixed size in each one you could just set the height to a pixel value.

Comment: FIXED!! It's not fixed with css, but it works anyway. I just added one more paragraph with br's in it. I know, it's not right, but as I said.. anyway :)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it didn't show before! It's not fixed number of paragraphs, and it's not fixed height of the paragraphs. Anyway I've done it with adding one more paragraph, so... everything's fine :).